# Google analytics, adwords, facebook data on my server

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I've got client who has several different websites, each website having Google analytics account. 
Our marketing department is also running Google Adwords/Facebook/Instagram ads for each of those websites.

I want data/leads from Google and Facebook on my local server. I also want real-time data that should automatically update from Google & Facebook with fixed time interval.

I've been Googling and experimenting with the Analytics API docs, but no luck.

Any one please help me to find better solution.

*#This question is not for this website but I didn't find any other option.*

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is you problem with the Analytics API ? Did you not get it to work, or did it not give you the data you wanted ?

Comment: Thank you for response. I want is there any option available to get all data of Google & Facebook on my local server.

Answer (score 0):

There are several services that your are looking for. Use this info like a getting started. Every service has his own simplicities and complexities.

### ***Adwords***

Use [Campaign Performance Report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report) to download your campaign's metrics. See examples in [PHP](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/reporting#download-a-criteria-performance-report-with-awql), [Java](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/java/reporting#download-a-criteria-performance-report-with-awql), [Python](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/python/reporting#download-a-criteria-performance-report-with-awql), etc.

### ***Analytics***

Use [RealTime API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get) to get real time data. See [examples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get#ejemplos)

Use [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) to get general data. See [examples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples)

There is a very useful tool: [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to see Analytics API working

### ***Facebook / Instagram***

Use [Ads Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api) to download your campaigns's metrics. See [examples](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/sdks)